# Will there be man-rated DreamChasers?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, commercial

The Sierra Nevada DreamChaser was a contender for the commercial crew program, but lost out when NASA chose both Boeing and SpaceX for their program.  However, they kept developing the craft for the second round of commercial cargo craft.  Is Sierra Nevada still developing a man-rated craft, or are they sticking to just unmanned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sierra Nevada's [web site](https://www.sncorp.com/what-we-do/dream-chaser-space-vehicle/) says:

"SNC's Dream Chaser® spacecraft is a multi-mission space utility vehicle designed for **transporting crew** and cargo to low-Earth orbit (LEO) destinations such as the International Space Station." (emphasis mine)

If you go to the PDF "[Dream Chaser Brochure](https://www.sncorp.com/media/2392/ssg_dream-chaser-spacecraft-bifold_for-web_4-4-18.pdf)", in addition to repeating the above, they say:

"Dream Chaser was originally designed as a crewed spacecraft, capable of carrying 
up to seven astronauts to and from the space station and other LEO destinations. The 
crewed Dream Chaser was developed in part under NASA’s Commercial Crew Program, 
and has environmental control and life support, windows for crew visibility, and an 
integral main propulsion system for abort capability and major orbital maneuvers."

Looks like they haven't given up, which is good. Keep at it, SNC!